# How to run schema file in DB2 Database

Tags: database, db2

I am very new to DB2, I have installed the DB2 setup and I created a new database.

Now I got a new schema file from the developers(Schema.sql).

I tried to execute using the "-tvf Schema.sql". but its giving following error.

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "-tvf schema.sql" was found following
"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "  " .
SQLSTATE=42601`

How to execute the file now.

Comment: Show the beginning of the file and how you execute it. Are you running it from the OS command line?

Comment: How did you submit the command?  Was it from a shell on Windows or Linux?  The -tvf option is valid only for the Db2 command-line-processor on the command line.  Specifically if you are using the *interactive* mode of the CLP then you cannot use that syntax. You have to use the batch mode like `db2 -tvf Schema.sql`

Comment: I am running the script from "DB2 command line processor".

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be running the interactive-mode "DB2 Command line processor".  This is the wrong tool for running batch scripts. Learn the difference by studying the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc-gentopic2.html).

On Windows, start > run > db2cwadmin.bat .  This will open the db2cmd.exe in administrative mode. When db2cmd.exe opens, use the CD command to change into the directory containing your "Schema.sql" file.  If the file expects a pre-existing connection to a database then use the command `db2 connect to ....` (specifying your Db2 database name and optionally the user and password ). You can then run the command `db2 -tvf Schema.sql`.

If you are unwilling or unable to use a command-line and if you prefer to use a graphical user interface, then you can also run scripts in GUI tools like 'IBM Data Studio' or 'DB Visualiser' or many similar free tools that work with Db2.

Answer (score 0):

First tell us in which OS you are trying to run it also if it is in remote mode or local.
You have to establish connection to your database and before to run the schema file be sure you are connecting there with: `db2 get connection state`

When you will execute the file and you are in the same path of the file to execute try to run it on this way: `db2 -stvf schema.sql`
so with the Flag "s" this will stop in the line that failed and this will help you to prevent and make a better troubleshooting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31964351)